# Create Trigger that updates the same table before (or after ??) the Insert

Tags: mysql, query

I have just started using triggers and one thing that I would need to do is to create a trigger that updates the same table that's inserting the row.

TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `city_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `country` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_country_id` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`country_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6009 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `populate_country_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `city`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.country_id = 0

THEN
    UPDATE city
    INNER JOIN country B ON city.country = B.country
    SET NEW.country_id = B.country_id;

END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL is just returning: Can't update table 'city' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Is there any way I can make this work?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Trigger can NOT alter the table which altering fires this thigger. No exclusions.

Comment: It is "wrong" to have both `country` and `country_id` in the `city` table.  That redundant with the purpose of the `country` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `populate_country_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `city`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.country_id = (SELECT CASE WHEN NEW.country_id = 0
                                  THEN country_id 
                                  ELSE NEW.country_id END
                      FROM country 
                      WHERE country = NEW.country 
                      LIMIT 1); -- as a precaution
```

BEGIN-END and DELIMITER reassign are excess.

PS. If `NEW.country` value is absent in `country` table then ... anycase inserted data is wrong.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much Akina! This works perfectly!

Still getting my head around these triggers! Once again thank you!

Comment: Hello @Akina can you help me with some query that it's almost same that yours?

Comment: @MauEspaña Create your own thread, maybe refer to this one.